# Reveal drop down only on click instead of on hover for desktop screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.0. Currently for desktop screens, when someone **hovers** on menu items a drop down gets displayed but I want them to **click** the menu item to reveal the drop down similar to what happens in the mobile version.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TutorialsPoint</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">SVN</a></li>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               Java <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">jmeter</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">EJB</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Jasper Report</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I have improved the contents and title by rewording them a bit. Library names are not required in title because they can be added as tags. If your question is specific to a certain version of the library, you can link the version specific tag also like I have done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desktop version for 3.0.0 does not open up the menu unless you click on it - http://jsfiddle.net/b2qhqn6w/show/

If your menu is opening when you hover, you probably have extra script or CSS making this happen (that you need to remove)

Comment: okay got it!! but what if i want it to to be clicked and open between screen range of 768px to 1024 px. As currently desktop is hovered and less than 768px is clicked.

Comment: I assume there was extra script to make it open on hover?